# How to create a overlay layout upon a listview

Tags: android, overlay

I have a listview that will be filled with `AsyncTask` and at the bottom edge of the app I need to show a fixed overlay layout like this:

[image]

But I can't figure it out how I can do this in xml?
This is my present layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <!-- Probably I need to do something here  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/ Take this :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Daniel has suggested, use a `RelativeLayout` because it allows stacking of components(same with `FrameLayout` and `SurfaceView`). The following code will give you the layout you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/transparentBlack"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
       android:text="Medium Text"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
       android:text="Large Text"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       android:textColor="@color/white" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the code above, the color hex values used for `transparentBlack` is `#95000000` and `white` is `#ffffff`.

Here is an excellent tutorial on the basics of UI design in android: [Android User Interface Design: Layout Basics](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/).

Comment: Thanks it is perfectly working! I am going to read through the link you give :)

Comment: What if you want to be able to scroll the bottom-most item above the overlay button?

Comment: @l33t Say you are using an `ArrayList` to hold list objects. Add an `empty` spacer item to the end of this list. In `getView()` of your adapter => when (position == mArrayList.size-1), set height of `convertView` to your `overlay's` height => set visibility of convertView to `View.INVISIBLE`. Haven't tried this - so this approach may need some modifications. If you'd like, you can edit my answer with your final implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Change the parent layout to `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` and position the fixed view at the same level of the `ListView` (but after the `ListView`)

Something like:

```
---> RelativeLayout
    --> ListView
    --> Any view as the fixed view
```

You can then align the fixed view to the bottom of the wrapping `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <!-- Here you should position the fixed view  -->
</RelativeLayout>
```